# Repmgr fail to register standby in claster, what did i miss?

Tags: database, postgresql, centos, database-replication

Problem with repmgr:
[failed to register in claster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcMF0.png)

PLEASE SAY ME, WHAT DID I MISS?

MASTER CONFIG:

```
failover=automatic
follow_command='repmgr standby follow -f /etc/repmgr.conf --log-to-file'
cluster=cluster1
node=1
node_name=node100
conninfo='host=192.168.22.200 port=6432 user=repmgr dbname=repmgr'
master_response_timeout=30
pg_bindir=/usr/local/bin/
service_start_command = systemctl start postgresql-9.6
service_stop_command = systemctl stop postgresql-9.6
service_restart_command = systemctl restart postgresql-9.6
```

STANDBY CONFIG:

```
failover=automatic
follow_command='repmgr standby follow -f /etc/repmgr.conf --log-to-file'
cluster=cluster1
node=3
node_name=replica
conninfo='host=slav port=6432 user=repmgr dbname=repmgr'
master_response_timeout=30
pg_bindir=/usr/local/bin/
service_start_command = systemctl start postgresql-9.6
service_stop_command = systemctl stop postgresql-9.6
service_restart_command = systemctl restart postgresql-9.6
```

REPMGR LOG:

```
[2017-08-09 10:36:37] [WARNING] No record found for node 3 
[2017-08-09 10:36:37] [ERROR] No metadata record found for this node - terminating 
[2017-08-09 10:36:37] [HINT] Check that 'repmgr (master|standby) register' was executed for this node
```

BUT WHEN TRY TO REGISTER NODE AS STANDBY:

```
-bash-4.2$ repmgr -f /etc/repmgr.conf standby register
ERROR: Node 3 exists already with node_name "replica"
```

Comment: NOW THE ERROR ON STANDBY: [ERROR] This node is marked as inactive and cannot be used for failover

Answer (score 0):

nub answer, maybe help
1. unregister standby 
2. ALTER USER repmgr SET search_path TO repmgr_test, "$user", public;
3. try register

conninfo='host=slav port....  use ip too